# how can i create a loop in my SQL query that will look for each week out of the year and return the top 10 values for each week?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query that returns the total number of submissions by person per week.  Like Below...

```
Person     WeekNumber     Total
ABC            1            12
ADE            1            10
ACD            1             8
LKJ            2             15
HJK            2             14
FGH            2             12
```

So far, I have the query to do everything EXCEPT being able to select the top Person from EACH WEEK.  I am thinking I might need to use a loop to do this but just trying to see if anyone might have a better/easier idea?

Here is my query:

```
Select sub.Person, sub.WeekNumber, sum(sr_id_count) as TotalSRID
from
(
    SELECT
    Person,
    DATEDIFF(week, '2016-12-25', create_date) AS WeekNumber,
    count(SR_ID) as SR_ID_COUNT
    from [dbo].[tbl_Hist]
    where create_date >= '01/01/2017'
        and SR_STatus <> 'Canceled'
        and Created_by <> 'System'
    group by person, create_date
) sub
group by sub.Person, sub.WeekNumber
order by WeekNumber, TotalSRID desc
```

Comment: Your syntax is SQL Server, but the question is tagged MySQL.

Comment: I apologize, edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is SQL Server, so I will assume that is the database you are using.  If so, you can use `row_number()`.  To get the top person per week:

```
select *
from (select Person, datediff(week, '2016-12-25', create_date) AS WeekNumber,
             count(SR_ID) as SR_ID_COUNT,
             row_number() over (partition by datediff(week, '2016-12-25', create_date order by count(SR_ID) desc) as seqnum
      from [dbo].[tbl_Hist]
      where create_date >= '2017-01-01' and SR_STatus <> 'Canceled' and
            Created_by <> 'System'
      group by person, datediff(week, '2016-12-25', create_date)
     ) sub 
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want the top 10 per week, then use `seqnum <= 10`.

Comment: This is near perfect, but for an hour I've been trying to incorporate this part of the code back in because it is necessary and I cannot get it to give me the correct results still. AGH.

sum(sr_id_count) as TotalSRID
from
(
    SELECT
    Person,
    DATEDIFF(week, '2016-12-25', create_date) AS WeekNumber,
    count(SR_ID) as SR_ID_COUNT

The count comes first, then the sum of the count because I need the TOTAL number per person for that week.  any way you know of to incorporate the (sum(count(sr_ID)) in there somehow?